# Could I get an explanation on why this would conditionally converge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, divergent-series, absolute-convergence, conditional-convergence

$$\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty \frac{\cos(n\pi)}{\ln(n)^2}$$

I'm not sure how this would conditionally converge, according to my calculations I would assume it's absolutely converge.

Comment: the numerator oscillates, but if you take the $| . |$, it eventually decreases to something manageable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$.

This converges by the alternating series test.  Compare to the harmonic series to see that it does not converge absolutely.

Comment: What did you do to get it to equal (-1)^n?

Comment: Where does $n\pi$ live on the trigonometric circle, in your opinion?

Comment: @Bernard I'm not sure, that's why I'm asking

Comment: Well, it's at the origin of the trigonometric circle if $n$ is even, at the diametrically opposed point if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Use induction if you want.  $\cos(0) = 1$, $\cos((n+1)\pi) = \cos(n \pi) \cos(\pi) - \sin(n\pi) \sin(\pi) = - \cos(n\pi)$.